# why my splash screen don't show the images?

Tags: android

I've created one splash screen with android studio 0.1, but when I test it on my phone(nexus s) in debugging mode with usb the image isn't show.. why?

this is the MainActivity

```
package com.example.splash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Handler x = new Handler();
    x.postDelayed(new SplashHandler(), 7000);



}
class SplashHandler implements Runnable{

    public void run(){


     startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), Main.class));
        MainActivity.this.finish();


    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is Main

```
package com.example.splash;


import android.app.Activity;

public class Main extends Activity {   

}
```

this is Splash.xml

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/splash">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you Have you copied the image to this folder

Comment: What's the name of the image file? splash or splash.jpg?

Comment: the image is in the folder and it's png, the name is splash

Comment: @powerj1984 do you have any documentation saying not you splash screen. Could you post a link for the same for clarity

Comment: http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/. i guess this supports @powerj1984

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdIG7kYjYbE I've see this tutorial but more superficially..

Comment: @Malloctry try it on eclipse. just a suggestion. coz it worked on my device.

Comment: @Raghunandan here is a post by a Google Android designer saying not to use them: https://plus.google.com/115995639636688350464/posts/imEP4dexnAg

Comment: @powerj1984 i agree with you the splash screen does nothing and it is not required in this case. read the whole article in both blog links posted by me and yours.

Comment: I read the article and I realized that It was not a good idea! I wanted to use it only to not show the menu directly, because aesthetically I did not like!

Comment: Yeah splash images look pretty, much like the dashboard layout - but really end up hurting usability! It's better if you can find a way to get your style across using the app itself :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a application context. To know when to use activity context and application context pls check the link below especially the answer by commonsware

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

I tested your code in the post. It works on my device samsung galaxy s3. Only Change i made was having a imageview in the RelativeLayout and set the image for the same in onCreate().
I also used a activity context. Other than that your code is fine.

Splash screen using handler

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
private static final int SPLASH_TIME = 2 * 1000;// 3 seconds delay

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.afor);
    try {
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,
                MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            Splash.this.finish();
        }     
    }, SPLASH_TIME);
        }

    } catch(Exception e){}
}
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffaa">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

`Class c extends Activity` to `Class c extends AppCompatActivity`.

Works to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String EmpID;
int requestCode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);          
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), Main.class));
                 MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
   }
}
```

**Splash.xml**      Remember splash image should be png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/splash">
```

Comment: i read somewhere on SO that sleep inside a thread is not a good design.

Comment: Could be not sure. But never created a prblm for me as there is try, catch and finally..

Comment: the image still does not appear.

Comment: i am not talking about the problem you can search on SO to be sure. I only said its a bad design

Comment: @Malloc try the below. the answer works on my phone and pls use a activity context. to know why check the link posted by me in the answer

Comment: are you able to see your image in Eclipse XML Editor--> Graphical Layout??

Comment: @Malloc i tested your code on the phone it works fine for me. I only made few minor changes.

Comment: yes, I can see my image in the graphical Layout!( I'm using Android studio not Eclipse!)