# Splash screen won't display before main actvity

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

i'm developing an android app but can't seem to get the splash screen to start before the main activity yet on all my other app's this has been no problem

What could be the problem here? There's no problem in the code.

```
package com.example.soundboardapp;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class splash extends Activity {
    private long ms = 0;
    private long splashTime = 2000;
    private boolean splashActive = true;
    private boolean paused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread mythread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    while (splashActive && ms < splashTime) {
                        if (!paused)
                            ms = ms + 100;
                        sleep(100);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } finally {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        mythread.start();
    }
}
```

Theres a splash activity to correspond to the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/intro22"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" >



    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="184dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/. some people discourage splash screens

Comment: also your splash screen does nothing so why do you want to have it?

Comment: I asked for help on getting it working not for someone to tell to not to use it...

Comment: Please post your _AndroidManifest.xml_.

Comment: @GeoffBolton check the link. Splash Screen using a handler.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750059/why-my-splash-screen-dont-show-the-images/16750316#16750316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have the `splash` activity set as the starting activity of your application. Check the *AndroidManifest.xml* file if you have something like this there:

```
<activity android:name="splash" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Let me know if that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a thread,
instead of the entire thread, use this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);

}, splashTime);
```