# Showing activity from onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-activity

### Problem Description

I have two activities in my application `MainActivity` and `BannerActivity`. From the main activity I start `BannerActivity` in `onCreate` method. But I first I see `MainActivity` screen for a second and then `BannerActivity` screen.

### Question

How I can do so that `BannerActivity` will be shown first and after countdown timer will stop and `BannerActivity` will close after that `MainActivity` come to the screen.

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Show banner activity for several seconds then close it. */
    Intent bannerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BannerActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(bannerIntent);   
}
};
```

#### BannerActivity

```
public class BannerActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Make banner fullscreen. */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_banner);

    /* Launch count down timer for several seconds. */
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { /* Not used. */ }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            BannerActivity.this.finish();
        }

    }.start();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /* Lock back button presses. */
    super.onBackPressed();
}

};
```

Comment: why don´t You start BannerActivity as your main activity? Then you could set here an intent after timer stops to start MainActivity...

Comment: @ViTO you can just have setContentView replaced as required in MainActivity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750059/why-my-splash-screen-dont-show-the-images/16750316#16750316. Check this link. Might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SplashScreen:

http://www.thiagorosa.com.br/en/tutorial/part01-splash-screen

```
public class GameSplash extends Activity {

// time to wait on the splash screen
private static final int SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // do any heavy initialization here

                // wait a few seconds before going to the next screen
                sleep(SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
            finally {
                // start the level selection screen
                Intent intentSelect = new Intent(GameSplash.this, GameSelect.class);
                startActivity(intentSelect);
            }
        }
    }.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // ignore any key press on the splash screen
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this way first need to load xml layout

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_banner);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

or try to put in manifest like

```
 <activity
        android:name=".BannerActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           >
```

Answer (score 0):

Run first BannerActivity and in the contdown run MainActivity rather than BannerActivity.this.finish();

Answer (score 0):

You can start with BannerActivity and then when the time expires you go to MainActivity and clear the history stack by using this intent flag (so that you can't go back to the BannerActivity using the back button).

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Answer (score 0):

You need splash screen. Try this:

Start `BanerActivity` first. And make its `onCreate` like

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

            int wait = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    super.run();

                    while (wait < 5000) { //Wait of 5 seconds
                        sleep(500);
                        wait += 500;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                } finally {

                    Intent i = new Intent(BanerActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        welcomeThread.start();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why do you need the while loop ? Can't you just write Thread.sleep(5000)

Comment: Yes. I just copied it from my working code. Didn't modify :) @blackbelt

Answer (score 0):

Swap the activites on the Manifest to decide which activity is run first :

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackagename.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackagename.BannerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The BannerActivity should have the `<intent-filter>` tag and set as Main and Launcher as the example. This will make Banner activity as the Initial Activity when you start your application.

After that you can just implement countdowntimer and start MainActivity when the timer ends.

Hope this helps, Good Luck ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this also in your Banner Activity

use this code in oncreate method in banner activity

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to make the `BannerActivity` the launcher activity and modify the `CountDownTimer` to be

```
 @Override
 public void onFinish() 
 {
         Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(mainIntent); 
         finish();
 }
```

then adjust the `manifest` file to make the  `BannerActivity` as the `launcher activity` and remove it from the `MainActivity`