# android noclassdeffoound error

Tags: android, android-manifest

This is my splash screen activity im trying to display a particular image for a period of time and when it is supposed to go to the second class it gives me an error 
as no classdeffounderror

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layoutt1);
mSplashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                while (shouldContinue) {

                    synchronized (this) {
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(5000);
                        shouldContinue = false;

                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            } finally {
                finish();

                // Run next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                shouldContinue = false;

                // stop();
            }

        }
    };

    mSplashThread.start();
```

}

My logcat shows

```
06-10 14:38:00.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5853): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bara.fol.MainActivity
```

Could not find class 'com.bara.fol.MainActivity', referenced from method com.bara.fol.Main$1.run

and this is my manifest.xml present inside the application tag.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" ></activity>
```

Comment: are you using any IDE , i means laoutt1 , with double T thats correct right ??

Comment: <activity android:name="com.bara.fol.MainActivity" ></activity>

Comment: are you sure MainActivity in same package?

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid yea thats correct

Comment: @sunil yes they are in the same package.

Comment: @Segi ive tried that too still a no go

Comment: MainActivity.java is under which pkg?

Comment: @YajneshwarMandal com.bara.fol

Comment: Did you use library in your second activity?

Comment: is your code going to the intent?? because in code you have written finish before launching the intent!!

Comment: use  finish(); after startActivity() statement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750059/why-my-splash-screen-dont-show-the-images/16750316#16750316. try this fro spalsh. use a hanlder. sleep inside thread is a bad design

Comment: @No_Rulz yes the viewpager library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are using finish before start intent, it should be written after startintent call and as you said you are using a library follow these steps and clean your project:

project right click properties-> Java BuildPath select Library and add external .jar the follow these step.

Go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path than select Order and export tab. Set external .jar library checked and up it into top of the list. And clean and rebuild.

Comment: ive already referenced the viewpager lib but no i did also reference the support lib and it worked. thxx @Skygeek

Comment: if you are able to solve the problem, give me a +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code for splash screen...It's work for me

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 

        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                StartActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                StartActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste your external `jar` in `libs` directory and then give path from your `libs` directory
`right click` on project-->`properties`-->`java build path`-->`add external jar's`-->`select your libs directory`

Answer (score -1):

I think you did not declare the Activity in the manifest.xml.

Answer (score -1):

In the manifest, you have declared ".Main" instead of ".MainActivity"